# Creating a sensor in airflow using a virtual python environment

Tags: python, airflow

I have been using successfully airflow python tasks with a virtual environment thanks to the `@task.virtualenv(requirements=[...])` decorator.

However, is it possible to also write sensors in python that make use of external environments? There is a `@task.sensor` decorator but I can't figure out how to use simultaneously with a virtual environment.

To reproduce, here is an example of two DAGs, assuming a package (pymsteams in this case but could be anything not part of the airflow environment):

```py
import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@task.virtualenv(requirements=["pymsteams"])
def virtual_env_task():
    import pymsteams


@task.sensor
def virtual_env_sensor():
    import pymsteams

    return True


@dag(start_date=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1), catchup=False)
def virtual_env_task_dag():
    virtual_env_task()


@dag(start_date=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1), catchup=False)
def virtual_env_sensor_and_task_dag():
    virtual_env_sensor() >> virtual_env_task()


virtual_env_task_dag()
virtual_env_sensor_and_task_dag()
```

`virtual_env_task_dag` succeeds as `pymsteams` gets installed in a virtual env environment, `virtual_env_sensor_and_task_dag` however fails as I can't figure a way of how to incorporate a virtual environment into a sensor.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and indicate what issues you found? 
Have you tried applying both decorators to the function? Or using one of the Classic options such as [PythonSensor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of `@task.sensor`? Or is `@task.external_python` appropriate here?

Comment: Thanks, just clarified and added an example. I don't think PythonSensor or `@task.external_python` are relevant here as they don't allow virtual envs either.

Comment: As for now (Airflow 2.8.1) there is no TaskFlow virtual env sensor neither PythonVirtualenvSensor